# Strange NSLog errors. Memory leaks

Tags: ios, xcode, memory-leaks, nslog

When i running my app output shows me a lot of this strings:

```
2012-05-12 14:41:52.542 PermTour[1688:15c0b] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x5c39520 of class NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
```

And i know that the problem in this part of code. Because, when i comment it, output is empty.

```
 for(int i=0;i<[dataBase.allDataBase count];i++){
        aPLace = [dataBase.allDataBase objectAtIndex:i];
        name = [aPLace.name lowercaseString];
        description = [aPLace.description lowercaseString];
        if (!([name rangeOfString:searchText].location == NSNotFound) || !([description rangeOfString:searchText].location == NSNotFound)){
            [foundedPlaces addObject:aPLace];
        }

    }
```

Any ideas? Thnx

UPD.

When i comment all code and it looks like:

```
for(int i=0;i<[dataBase.allDataBase count];i++){
        aPLace = [dataBase.allDataBase objectAtIndex:i];
        name = [aPLace.name lowercaseString];
        //description = [aPLace.description lowercaseString];
        /*
        if (!([name rangeOfString:searchText].location == NSNotFound) || !([description rangeOfString:searchText].location == NSNotFound)){
            [foundedPlaces addObject:aPLace];
        }
         */

    }
```

Still memory leaking.. So what you think write now?

UPD 2
[image]

Comment: is this method is called on background thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are dealing with a lot of data(memory), then it is always preferable to use `NSAutoreleasePool`.

EDIT -

```
-(returnType)yourMethod:(returnType)parameter @autoreleasepool
{
    @autoreleasepool
    {
         //method body.
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: could you explain how should i use it?

Comment: XCode said me that i cant use it in ARC

Comment: @EugeneTrapeznikov - i have checked this and updated my code to support ARC, hope finally this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this error message is class initialisation methods (for example `+initialize`, `+load` or other custom methods).

The solution for me was simply to create an autorelease pool, like this:

```
@autoreleasepool
{
     initThis();
     [That init];
}
```

The `@autoreleasepool` keyword may be used in both ARC and non-ARC projects with similar semantics.

Here is the [small print](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/nsapplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html) on the matter:

> The NSApplication class sets up autorelease pools (instances of the
>   NSAutoreleasePool class) during initialization and inside the event
>   loop—specifically, within its initialization (or sharedApplication)
>   and run methods. Similarly, the methods the Application Kit adds to
>   NSBundle employ autorelease pools during the loading of nib files.
>   These autorelease pools aren’t accessible outside the scope of the
>   respective NSApplication and NSBundle methods. Typically, an
>   application creates objects either while the event loop is running or
>   by loading objects from nib files, so this lack of access usually
>   isn’t a problem. **However, if you do need to use Cocoa classes within
>   the main() function itself (other than to load nib files or to
>   instantiate NSApplication), you should create an autorelease pool
>   before using the classes and then release the pool when you’re done.**
>   For more information, see NSAutoreleasePool in the Foundation
>   Framework Reference.

Comment: @EugeneTrapeznikov Sorry, I don't understand.